# Batch or PowerShell to Find a File name with ANY 2 extensions in it Example File.docx.js Could be File.Docx.locky

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell-3.0

Since a lot of Ransomware puts an extension onto the existing file extension of a file, I am looking for code that will find any file in a directory that contains two file extensions. It does not matter what those extensions are, just that they exist.
Example `MyFile.Docx.JS` or `Myfile.jpg.locky`

I already have code that loops through the 'Documents' folder of a user and looks for a .locky extension. And it works well. Problem is, I do not want to keep looking for specific extensions/signatures of Ransomware and since they typically re-create the existing file with an additional extension, I thought this would be a good way to create a early warning hourly check.

Comment: In other words: You are looking for files with names that contain exactly 2 periods. The periods must not be consecutive, or at either end of the name. Sounds like a fairly simple pattern matching algorithm to implement.

Comment: @IInspectable, if you are thinking of something like `*.*.*`, it does not work as this seems to match all files...

Comment: Yes, that would work - thx

Comment: tried the Dir *.*. variations, did not work

Comment: `dir /B /A:-D * | findstr /R "^.*\..*\..*$"` returns all files containing two or more periods; `dir /B /A:-D * | findstr /R "^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*$"` returns all files containing exactly two periods...

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. Appreciated!!

Comment: That's not in any documentation I have see, with the ^[^.].

Comment: This is `findstr`-specific -- type `findstr /?` into a command prompt window to see what it means and to find further options...

Answer (score 1):

#### Two File Extensions Or More

If you want to return all files that contain at least two file extensions (such containing two or more periods in their names), you can simply pipe the output of a `dir` command into `findstr` (a tool for searching strings and supporting a tiny set of regular expressions), which filters out all files with less than two periods in their names:

```
dir /B /A:-D * | findstr /R "^.*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*$"
```

If you do not want to allow any of the extensions to be empty, change the search string like this:

```
dir /B /A:-D * | findstr /R "^.*\.[^.][^.]*\.[^.][^.]*$"
```

Use a `for /F` loop to do something on each matching file:

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D * ^| findstr /R "^.*\.[^.][^.]*\.[^.][^.]*$"
') do (
    rem // Do something with each file using `%%F`:
    echo(%%F
)
```

---

Alternatively, you could use two nested `for` loops like this (this fails if a file extension is empty):

```
for %%I in ("*") do (
    for %%J in ("%%~nI") do (
        if not "%%~xJ"=="" (
            rem // Do something with each file using `%%~I`:
            echo(%%~I
        )
    )
)
```

---

#### Exactly Two File Extensions

If you want to return all files that contain exactly two file extensions (such containing exactly two periods in their names), you can simply pipe the output of a `dir` command into `findstr` (a tool for searching strings and supporting a tiny set of regular expressions), which filters out all files with less than two periods in their names:

```
dir /B /A:-D * | findstr /R "^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*$" returns all files containing exactly two periods...
```

If you do not want to allow any of the extensions to be empty, change the search string like this:

```
dir /B /A:-D * | findstr /R "^[^.]*\.[^.][^.]*\.[^.][^.]*$"
```

Use a `for /F` loop to do something on each matching file:

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D * ^| findstr /R "^[^.]*\.[^.][^.]*\.[^.][^.]*$"
') do (
    rem // Do something with each file using `%%F`:
    echo(%%F
)
```

---

Alternatively, you could use three nested `for` loops like this (this fails if a file extension is empty):

```
for %%I in ("*") do (
    for %%J in ("%%~nI") do (
        for %%K in ("%%~nJ") do (
            if not "%%~xJ"=="" (
                if "%%~xK"=="" (
                    rem // Do something with each file using `%%~I`:
                    echo(%%~I
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell you can do something like this in one line and save the results into a text file :

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*$"} | % { $_.FullName } | Out-File c:\LogDoubleExtensions.txt
```